# How to run a SQL script in tsql

Tags: linux, t-sql, freetds

I'm using tsql (installed with FreeTDS) and I'm wondering if there's a way to run a SQL script in tsql from the command line and get the result in a text file.

For example, in psql I can do:

```
psql -U username -C "COPY 'SELECT * FROM some_table' to 'out.csv' with csv header"
```

Or:

```
psql -U username -C "\i script.sql"
```

And in script.sql do:

```
\o out.csv
SELECT * FROM  some_table;
```

Is there a way for doing this in tsql? I have read the linux man page and search everywhere but I just don't find a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really didn't find how to do this and I'm starting to thinks it just can't be done in tsql. However I solved for my specific problem redirecting the stdin and stdout. I use a bash script like this:

```
tsql connection parameters < tsql_input.sql > tsql_output.csv
lines=`cat tsql_output.csv | wc -l`

# The output includes the header info of tsql and the "(n number of rows)" message
# so I use a combination of head and tail to select the lines I need
headvar=$((lines-2))
tailvar=$((lines-8))

head -$headvar tsql_output.csv | tail -$tailvar tsql_output.csv > new_output_file.csv
```

And that saves just the query result on 'new_output_file.csv'

Answer (score 6):

I think, you can try "bsqldb", see http://linux.die.net/man/1/bsqldb

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Thank you! `brew install freetds` on my Mac brought `bsqldb` down with it already. ex usage: `bsqldb -S $MSSQL_SERVER -U $MSSQL_USERNAME -P $MSSQL_PASSWORD -i test.sql`

Answer (score 1):

```
freebcp "select * from mytable where a=b" queryout sample.csv -U anoop -P mypassword -S hostname.com -D dbname -t , -c
```

This command woks like a charm. Kudos to FreeTDS...

Answer (score -1):

```
tsql -U username -P password -p 1433 > out.csv <<EOS SELECT * FROM some_table; go EOS
```

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit?

Comment: Just doesn't work for me as-is with your syntax. Did you test before posting?