# Dump tsql result to a file

Tags: bash, t-sql

Id like to run mssql queries in a bash script with tsql command. Thats okay, i can connect and run manualy. I tried to save the result to a file with this script but no success.

```
> tsql -connection parameters- < tsql_input.sql > tsql_output.csv
```

where tsql_input.sql is :

```
select ... from .... ;
```

or

```
> tsql -connection parameters- < sql_cmd
```

where sql_cmd is :

```
echo "SELECT ... FROM ...;\n
GO\n
exit\n
" > out.csv
```

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

Use bcp.exe
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms162802(v=sql.120).aspx

Sample:
bcp.exe "SELECT Name FROM AdventureWorks.Sales.Currency" queryout Currency.Name.dat -T -c

Comment: Thank you, but I need Debian to use it.

Comment: Anything else ? :)

Comment: look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078869/how-to-run-a-sql-script-in-tsql