# How to install freetds in Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, freetds, unixodbc

I am trying to connect to MSSQL server from Ubuntu. I have installed freetds like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149395/what-are-some-ways-of-accessing-microsoft-sql-server-from-linux).

[image]

However, when I try to configure /etc/odbc.ini and enter a driver path I have no driver at location `/usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so`.

[image]

Can someone help me to install freetds and to configure odbc to use it?
*edit1: I have found libtdsodbc.so in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc. Should I use that driver/path?

Comment: check my the steps I followed here, hope that help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725523/working-with-nodejs-mssql-at-linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 36):

I've created a Vagrant box which has a full installation example here: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-python3-vagrant/

...but here are the basic steps.

*(NOTE: change ***dbserver.domain.com*** to your server hostname or IP)*

```
# Install pre-requesite packages
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-dev freetds-bin tdsodbc
```

Point odbcinst.ini to the driver in /etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = v0.91 with protocol v7.2
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

Create your DSNs in /etc/odbc.ini:

```
[dbserverdsn]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = dbserver.domain.com
Port = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.2
```

...and your DSNs in /etc/freetds.conf:

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version, use:
    # 7.3 for SQL Server 2008 or greater (tested through 2014)
    # 7.2 for SQL Server 2005
    # 7.1 for SQL Server 2000
    # 7.0 for SQL Server 7
    tds version = 7.2
    port = 1433

    # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
    # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff

    # Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10
    
    # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
    # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
    # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
    text size = 64512

# A typical Microsoft server
[dbserverdsn]
    host = dbserver.domain.com
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.2
```

After completing this, you can test your connection by attempting to connect with tsql (to test the FreeTDS layer) and isql (for the unixODBC through FreeTDS stack).

Comment: I'm new in this. I suppose I shoud change `Server = dbserver.domain.com` with IP of my server? Is this how I use tsql `tsql -S dbserverdsn` or should I write IP there? When I use `tsql -S dbserverdsn` I get `Error 100 (severity 11): unrecognized msgno
Error 20009 (severity 9):Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
 OS error 111, "Connection refused" There was a problem connecting to the server`

Comment: there should be tsql -S dbserverdsn <userid> <password>

Comment: I checked the tds version with `tsql -C` and saw it was 4.2. I replaced the 7.2's above with 4.2 and that seemed to remove the `msgno error`

Comment: @FlipperPA - wow thank you for this solution - I am able to connect QGIS Destop to MS SQL Server on a Linux Mint desktop, which I haven't been able to figure out for nearly a decade!

Answer (score 22):

The version available via `apt-get` is a really old version. To get a newer version:

```sh
sudo apt-get install wget
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev

# find latest version of FreeTDS ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/

wget ftp://ftp.freetds.org/pub/freetds/stable/freetds-1.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf freetds-1.2.tar.gz
cd freetds-1.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-tdsver=7.3
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Just FYI: Current stable release version is `1.12` (2019/07).

Comment: Very useful, thanks!

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 22.10! Thank you wery much!

Answer (score 0):

in freedts.conf

```
[Server80]
        host = example.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

in odbc.ini

```
[MSSQL8]
Driver          = FreeTDS
Description     = Sybase JDBC Server
Trace           = No
Servername      = Server80
Database        = DBNAME
UID             = sa
ClientCharset   = UTF-8
```

in odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=v0.63 with protocol v8.0
Driver=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=2
```

Comment: It seems working with `sudo apt install -y freetds-bin` (!)