# Non-Emulated Prepared Statement support from MS SQL Server through PHP on Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, freetds

**Summary**

I'm attempting to use prepared statements to stop SQL Injections, but am unable to find the support I need to guarantee it is working properly.

---

**Scenario**

I am hosting a site on Linux which is connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server with FreeTDS version 0.91, specifically using FreeTDS's `dblib`. I have set the `tds` version to 7.4 for the database connection, and am using PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) object.

According to the [FreeTDS documentation](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm), 4.2 does not support prepared statements:

> TDS 4.2 has limitations
>
> - ASCII only, of course.
> - RPC is not supported.
> - BCP is not supported.
> - varchar fields are limited to 255 characters. If your table defines
>     longer fields, they'll be truncated.
> - dynamic queries (also called prepared statements) are not supported.

However there is nothing indicating that 7.4 doesn't support prepared statements, which gives me reasonable confidence they at least won't throw a driver error.

PHP's PDO supports connection specific attributes via [`PDO::setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php).
I am interested in `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to set all errors as exceptions, and `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to force the database to do prepared statements if compatible.

---

**Issue**

When testing the connection, I receive the following error:

> Database error: SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support setting attributes

Without being able to set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, I am unable to guarantee the database is actually executing the prepared statements as intended.

Is there anyway to modify my approach, or is there an alternative approach, to 
guarantee that prepared statements are being executed securely on an MS SQL Server from Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Use `ODBC` instead of `dblib`, which provides the full functionality of PDO.
Note that there is two possible configurations of ODBC: [standalone ODBC](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504140812/http://www.freetds.org:80/userguide/odbcinionly.htm) and [FreeTDS with ODBC driver](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504140959/http://www.freetds.org:80/userguide/odbcombo.htm). From my experience, to set the character set for a connection, it must be done through FreeTDS using the ODBC driver, making the combined configuration preferable.

---

**ODBC Setup**

I searched through many different StackOverflow posts and various documentation sources on the web on how to properly install ODBC. I pulled my solution from a mixture of the following three references:

- [unixODBC setup documentation](http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html)
- `FlipperPA`'s answer to [setting up FreeTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341510/how-to-install-freetds-in-linux) (incidentally done with ODBC)
- `Benny Hill`'s answer to this [setup issue with FreeTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066716/freetds-not-using-its-config)

Below is the list of steps I used to configure `ODBC` using `FreeTDS` on a Debian based system.

TDS 8.0 supports prepared statements.

NOTE: Will not support `SET NAMES a` or `SET CHARSET a` on a connection; character sets need to be defined using the combined config by setting a FreeTDS attribute. Using the standalone ODBC driver defaulted the charset to `ASCII`, which gave odd results. See my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for examples of possible issues.

**Install require packages:**

> sudo apt-get install freetds-bin freetds-common unixodbc tdsodbc
> php5-odbc

- `freetds-bin` provides FreeTDS, as well as `tsql` and `isql` (used for debugging later).
- `freetds-common` was already installed on the system, but does not include the two debugging tools. Installing `freetds-bin` at a later date after a config was defined cause no issue.
- `unixodbc` is the ODBC driver
- `tdsodbc` provides the TDS protocol for ODBC
- `php5-odbc` is the php module to used ODBC drivers. Note that your php version may differ from mine.

**Configure Standalone unixODBC**

ODBC driver settings in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[odbc]
Description     = ODBC driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so 
UsageCount      = 1
```

Create a system wide datasource name configuration in `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[datasourcename]
 Driver         = odbc
 Description    = Standalone ODBC
 Server         = <IP or hostname>
 Port           = <port>
 TDS_Version    = 8.0
```

**Configure unixODBC and FreeTDS:**

ODBC driver settings in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[odbc]
Description     = ODBC driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so 
UsageCount      = 1
```

Create a system wide datasource name configuration in `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[datasourcename]
Driver          = FreeTDS_odbc
Description     = Uses FreeTDS configuration settings defined in /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
Servername      = datasourcename
TDS_Version     = 8.0
```

Add the ODBC datasource name config to FreeTDS in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`:

```
[datasourcename]
    host = <IP or hostname>
    port = <port>
    client charset = UTF-8
    tds version = 8.0
    text size = 20971520
    encryption = required
```

> IMPORTANT: make sure that the odbc files are readable by the process
> that will be reading them. If you are running your webserver using a
> `www-data` user, they must have the proper permissions to read those
> files!

You can now set the connection character set in `freetds.conf` and connect to the database with PDO as

```
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:datasourcename');
```

**Testing:**

Use `tsql` to check that FreeTDS is configured and can connect to the database.

> tsql -S datasourcename -U username -P password

Use `isql` to check that ODBC is connecting properly.

> isql -v datasourcename username password

**Link ODBC with PHP:**

Add ODBC PHP module to `php.ini` by adding the following:

> extension = odbc.so

Note that your `php.ini` location will depend on what webserver you are using.
Use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and view it through the webserver to find its location.

**Restart Apache**

EDIT:
Added information regarding character set capabilities of the driver, as I ran into issues with the standalone ODBC configuration where it would ignore any attempt to change the connection's character set.

Comment: Hi Stewart, thanks for your post - I realise this was years ago, but I am left wondering why exactly this functionality isn't supported in freetds > 4.2?

Comment: It's been a long time. It's very possible this is supported in freetds > 4.2. I'll leave that to someone else to investigate.