# While running my app on bluemix getting error Can't open lib 'SQL Server'

Tags: python, linux, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, pyodbc

I am trying to create a cloudfaundry app on bluemix. It uses linux by default as a server. i am getting below error while i am tring to connect  sql server db on azure

error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL 
Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

The code for connecting to db is here . I am using flask

```
@app.route('/sql/<lat>/<long>') 
def api_sql(lat,long):
 cnxn =pyodbc.connect('DRIVER{SQLServer};SERVER=prashantvikramsingh.database.windows.net;DATABASE=Zillow;UID=UserId;PWD=pass')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534154/linux-python3-cant-open-lib-sql-server). How to do this step while deploying the app on bluemix. 
This step can be done in local machine. But how to do it on cloud? . Is there any way to fix this error

thse are the contents of envirnment.yml file in local

```
name: pyodbc-test
dependencies:
 - pyodbc
 - flask
 - itsdangerous
 - Jinja2
 - MarkupSafe
 - Werkzeug
 - unixODBC
```

Comment: I've tried a few options, but haven't been able to make any progress with this.  Microsoft are now a member of the cloud foundry foundation, so maybe reach out to them asking for help.

Comment: It's missing the SQL Server driver and I'm not sure there's going to be an easy way to install that.  The link you included requires sudo/root access and that's not possible on CF.  You would need a way to install w/out root.  Another possibility would be to make a package you can install with Conda, but the SQL Server driver is proprietary so I don't think you could legally do that (I'm not a lawyer though).  If you're willing to use FreeTDS, that maybe a possible solution.  Another might be using pymssql instead of ODBC.

Comment: @ChrisSnow will try that . thanks for all the help

Comment: @DanielMikusa  . Thank you. Will try with pymssql and post the updates if there is success.

Answer (score 0):

The `SQL Server` driver is for Windows only.

You'll want to look into installing and using either the FOSS `FreeTDS` or the Microsoft `ODBC Driver for Linux 13.1`:

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/install.htm
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/02/08/odbc-driver-13-1-for-linux-released/

Then, in your connection string, if you're using FreeTDS, for example:

```
cnxn =pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=prashantvikramsingh.database.windows.net;DATABASE=Zillow;UID=UserId;PWD=pass;TDS_Version=7.2')
```

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

I've used FreeTDS for years and it has treated me well. Good luck!