# How to configure the Database setting Django-MSSQL using django-pyodbc (ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pyodbc

I'm new to Django and currently trying to use another database to save my model (i.e. `MS SQL`). My database is deployed in a docker container:

```
903876e64b67        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/bin/sh -c /opt/mssq"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          0.0.0.0:8888->1433/tcp             nauseous_williams
```

I also create a new user for my login to the SQL Server.

`Username='kucing', password='xxxxx'`

With my user, I can use sqlcmd to access my DB as below:

`sqlcmd -S localhost,8888 -U kucing -P 'xxxxx'`

Therefore, I change my Django setting for my DB as shown here:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'videogame', #The DB name
    'USER': 'kucing',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '8888',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
    },
},
```

However when I run `python manage.py migrate`, I get an error related to authentication:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/luca/git/learnPython/DjangoTicTacToe/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
  self.connect()
File "/home/luca/git/learnPython/DjangoTicTacToe/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
  self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/home/luca/git/learnPython/DjangoTicTacToe/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 302, in get_new_connection
  timeout=timeout)
  pyodbc.Error: ('28000', "[28000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'kucing'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Did I wrongly set up my configuration? Should I update my setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manage to figure out the issue. Because, I'm running both the Django application and the MS SQL server in linux, I need to change my driver to `FreeTDS`. 
This link is useful: [How to install freetds in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341510/how-to-install-freetds-in-linux)

After I finish installing the FreeTDS driver on my host (Ubuntu), I updated the Databases setting as follow:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'videogame',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '8888',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            'unicode_results': True,
            'host_is_server': True,
            'extra_params': 'tds_version=7.0;',
            }
    }
}
```

Then I create a superuser using this command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

And Lastly, I do the Database migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations; python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're hosting on Windows, since you're attempting to connect to `localhost`. I'd highly recommend using the `django-pyodbc-azure` engine (https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure), as it can be used for both local SQL Server or on Azure, and is the best maintained Django SQL Server package I've seen over several years of use. To install:

```
pip install django-pyodbc-azure
```

This will also install the `pyodbc` dependency. Since you're running Django on Windows (otherwise, you wouldn't be connecting to localhost), you can use the native client. Here's what I'd start with for your settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'videogame',
        'USER': 'kucing',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '8888',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 13.0',
        },
    },
}
```

Also, you should **never** post your password on Stack Overflow! I would highly recommend changing it. Typically, if you post your password as `xxxxx` or something like that, people will understand why. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm using linux OSX. I've figured out the issue though