# Django app failed to connect with ms sql server 2014

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am new in django,stuck on migration process, as a beginner can not find valuable information from error message. Need help about migration and db connection with application process.

**pip list**

```
Django (1.11.2)
django-mssql (1.8)
mysqlclient (1.3.10)
pip (9.0.1)
pytz (2017.2)
setuptools (28.8.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
Python 3.6.1
```

**To install Python package manage for ms sql server used bellow command**

```
pip install django-mssql
```

**My app model is**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Video(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField("Title",max_length=250)
    embed_code=models.TextField("Embed code")
```

**My django application database settings is bellow**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'djangolife',# db name
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'DESKTOP-SVHDHF8\\MSSQLSERVER2014',#Sql server name
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'sa123',
    }
}
```

**Migration command**

```
 python manage.py makemigrations
```

**After execute the above migration command get bellow errors**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 184, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shamim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: This post can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202467/how-to-configure-the-database-setting-django-mssql-using-django-pyodbc-ubuntu-1

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and I found the reason is [django-mssql support Django 1.8](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dependencies) but you are using Django 1.11. Please downgrade your Django version or wait until the latest version will be supported.