# FreeTDS and unixodbc installation&configuration

Tags: sql-server, laravel, odbc, freetds, unixodbc

I've spend a lot of hours trying to install and configure freeTDS and unixodbc to make my LARAVEL app work with a mssql database.

First of all I installed the sybase and followed the instructions of this thread:
[Connect PHP to MSSQL via PDO ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc)

Of course it didn't work, so I looked for a log to know whatever was happening.

After I got the freetds.log I noticed that my freetds is using a 4.2 version to login and perform the database requests and it doesn't support it.

I get this error in the freetds.log.

```
NT login not support using TDS 4.x or 5.0
```

After this, I've tried to install freetds manually using this thread:
[How to install freetds in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341510/how-to-install-freetds-in-linux)

And even If when I execute tsql -C it shows that I'm using tds version= 7.4
on log keeps saying 4.2

What can I do? I'm desperated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I've found the answer.

If you have tried the posts that I said, the problem is that freetds is trying to use a freetds.conf in another location, so if you install freetds with a previous ./configure --with-tdsver=7.4 --sysconfdir /etc/freetds (that's the directory for this post [Connect PHP to MSSQL via PDO ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163776/connect-php-to-mssql-via-pdo-odbc))

it works