# GAE Laravel connect to external SQL Server get error

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, google-app-engine

I use Laravel + SQL Server deploy to GAE, when connect to external SQL Server, I get error

> could not find driver

but in my local environment it works, so hope someone can help.

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
```

database.php

```
'sqlsrv' => 
['driver' => 'sqlsrv',
'host' => 'host',
'port' => '1401',
'database' => 'database',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => '',
'prefix' => '',]
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel to SQL Server (sqlsrv). \[PDOException\] could not find driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860273/laravel-to-sql-server-sqlsrv-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure of the PHP version you use (for me homestead currently using php 7.1, so I installed php7.1-sybase)

sudo apt-get install freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc php7.1-sybase

Driver:

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 'port'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ]
```