# Laravel 8 PDOException: could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel

I am using php 8.1.3 for this project.
**My file .env connection:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=db_PendaftaranOnline
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**I get this error:**

```
PDOException: could not find driver in C:\laragon\www\project\registrasi-online-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\project\registrasi-online-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('dblib:host=192....', 'client', 'dbop', Array)
```

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: You need to enable `pdo_mysql` in `php.ini`

Comment: I am using laragon, and already done with this : extension=pdo_mysql

Comment: @aceraven777 what has `MySQL` to do with `SQLSrv = Microsoft SQL`? @DearJanice You are missing the SQLServer driver... you never installed it and it is a pain in where the sun does not shine...

Comment: sorry, didn't noticed that the `DB_CONNECTION` is `sqlsrv`. well @matiaslauriti is right. I'm not familiar with laragon. you have to find a way to enable `sqlsrv` on laragon.

Comment: But it's works yesterday, and for today I get that error. Can you give me reference to instal SQLServer driver @matiaslauriti ?

Comment: @DearJanice plz show contents of `config/database.php` (hide private fields) so we can see what driver you are setting

Comment: 'connections' => [
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
    ],


This one?

Comment: @ThanhDao please kinda check it ><

Comment: @DearJanice The driver you was set is `sqlsrv` (SQL server). There a lots of issues you may to check, at least I know only PHP ext installed/enabled (As I never worked PHP with SQLSV). This article may help you more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860273/laravel-to-sql-server-sqlsrv-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver.

Take a look at Laravel documentation and ensure your configuration fully activated https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#mssql-configuration

Comment: @DearJanice https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php, check the related links inside that blogpost