# I am facing this error at the time of artisan migration

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing this error at the time of configuration my laravel 6.2 project with PHP 7.2.5 to MSSQL SERVER and I have added in .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST="DESKTOP-AMCDA5K"
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE="AuditReferences"
DB_USERNAME="sa"
DB_PASSWORD="admin123"
DB_ENCRYPT=true
DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE=false
```

for view server connection page is here
[server login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZDeA.png)

and I have added all dll files in php.ini file setting and pdo_sqlsrv, sqlsrv are shown in phpinfo page

**$ php artisan migrate**

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type in ('U', 'V') and name = migrations)
 at C:\wamp64\www\Laravel\laravelProj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
668|         catch (Exception $e) {
> 669|             throw new QueryException(
670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
671|             );
672|         }
673|

Exception trace:

1   PDOException::("could not find driver") C:\wamp64\www\Laravel\laravelProj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

2   PDO::__construct("dblib:host=DESKTOP-AMCDA5K:1433;dbname=AuditReferences;charset=utf8", "sa", "admin123", []) C:\wamp64\www\Laravel\laravelProj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
```

Comment: Is this question can be solve by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860273/laravel-to-sql-server-sqlsrv-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

From my experience this is usually because the `host` in the `.env` file is incorrect.

Your host of `DB_HOST="DESKTOP-AMCDA5K"` seems weird at first glance (I'm assuming this is your PC name).

try using `DB_HOST=localhost` or `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` assuming the SQL server is located on the same machine as Laravel

Comment: I have used to host as localhost but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message, **the problem lay in the SQL driver.**

SQL driver facilitates the connection between the application and the database (vice versa). Generally we two types of SQL drivers: **ODBC and JDBC**
Anything went wrong with the SQL driver and/or its configuration/dependencies may result in such errors mentioned above.

You are being requested to take a **thorough examination of your local environment to find out what went wrong so far.**