# Data from MySQL and SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two databases one in MySQL and the other in SQL Server. I have a request table in MySQL with fields as `requestid` and `requestdatetime`. And in SQL Server I have a table named request desc with columns as `requestid` and `request_description`.

These tables are updated at different times throughout the day. How can I connect these two and get the details as `requestid`, `reqest_description` and `requestdatetime` based in the requestid taken from MySQL database?

Comment: Long story short, you can't easily connect MySQL to MS SQL Server. The best you can do is use something like [FreeTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/149418/378779), but that won't work for all situations. You should describe in more detail how frequently these tables get updated, and how frequently you want to query them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can perform a read query to the MySQL database request table from the SQL Server database then, set up an SQL Server job that syncs data between MySQL request table and another table with similar schema (lets call this duplicate table) in SQL Server. If that is possible then you can connect the duplicate table and the SQL Server request desc table. Make sure that the duplicate table and request table both contains similar data.